# How to create xml file from a multiple lines text file using python

Tags: python, xml, jenkins, junit

Im trying to create an xml which picks up values from each line of a text file

unittests.text file looks like this:

```
test_sm.py src/test/python/t0/cli/test_sm.py 4 0.864s pass 4 Skip 0 Fail 0
test_performance.py src/test/python/t0/backend/fs_tests/parse/test_performance.py 18 0.005s pass 18 Skip 0 Fail 0
AsyncService_test.py src/test/python/t0/ws/AsyncService_test.py 2 0.092s pass 2 Skip 0 Fail 0
test_bebundd.py src/test/python/t0/backend/test_bebundd.py 8 0.288s pass 8 Skip 0 Fail 0
test_utils.py src/test/python/t0/backend/inventory/test_utils.py 5 0.005s pass 5 Skip 0 Fail 0
FileSystemService.py src/test/python/t0/ws/filesystem/FileSystemService.py 3 0.136s pass 3 Skip 0 Fail 0
test_customerprocess.py src/test/python/t0/backend/test_customerprocess.py 14 8.659s pass 14 Skip 0 Fail 0
test_store.py src/test/python/t0/backend/fs_tests/test_store.py 12 2.061s pass 12 Skip 0 Fail 0
ChangeDefaultPassword_test.py src/test/python/t0/ws/ChangeDefaultPassword_test.py 7 1.073s pass 7 Skip 0 Fail 0
test_check_iothroughput.py node/src/test/python/t0/monitoring/test_check_iothroughput.py 18 0.025s pass 18 Skip 0 Fail 0
test_pidlockfile.py src/test/python/t0/test_pidlockfile.py 18 4.024s pass 18 Skip 0 Fail 0
CustomerWizardService_test.py src/test/python/t0/ws/CustomerWizardService_test.py 6 0.183s pass 6 Skip 0 Fail 0
test_option.py src/test/python/t0/backend/export/test_option.py 8 0.394s pass 8 Skip 0 Fail 0
test_discovery_test_report.py src/test/python/t0/wsgi/test_discovery_test_report.py 3 0.130s pass 3 Skip 0 Fail 0
test_syslog.py src/test/python/t0/backend/test_syslog.py 24 4.545s pass 24 Skip 0 Fail 0
```

I wrote script "output_unittests.py" for creating an xml but it's reading only from last line in unittests.txt file

output_unittests.py is as below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element

root = ET.Element('testsuite')
m1 = ET.Element('testcase')
root.append (m1)

lines = open("/tmp/unittest.txt").readlines()
for line in lines:
    split_line = line.split(' ')
    testfile= str(split_line\[0\])
    sep = '.'
    testname = str(testfile.split(sep, 1)\[0\])
    package = str(split_line\[1\])
    package2 = str(package.split(sep, 1)\[0\])
    classname = str(testname.replace("\_", ""))
    final_classname = str(package2 +"."+classname)
    tests = str(split_line\[2\])
    duration = str(split_line\[3\])
    ps = str(split_line\[2\])
    skp = str(split_line\[7\])
    fl = str(split_line\[-1\])
    root.set('errors', "0")
    root.set('failures' , '0')
    root.set('hostname' , 'devkvm01-jenkins')
    root.set('name' , 'unittest')
    root.set('skipped' , skp)
    root.set('tests' , tests)
    root.set('time' , duration)
    m1.set('classname' , final_classname)
    m1.set('file' , testfile)
    m1.set('name' , testname)
    m1.set('time' , duration)
    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    tree.write("jenkins_output.xml", encoding = "UTF-8", xml_declaration = True)
```

It created jenkins_output.xml  as below

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<testsuite errors="0" failures="0" hostname="devkvm01-jenkins" name="unittest" skipped="0" tests="24" time="4.545s"><testcase classname="src/test/python/t0/backend/test_syslog.testsyslog" file="test_syslog.py" name="test_syslog" time="4.545s" /></testsuite>
```

I need jenkins_output.xml to contain values of all the lines in unittests.text in the same format.. something like below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<testsuite errors="0" failures="0" hostname="devkvm01-jenkins" name="unittest" skipped="0" tests="3" time="0.130s"><testcase classname="src/test/python/t0/wsgi/test_discovery_test_report.testdiscoverytestreport" file="test_discovery_test_report.py" name="test_discovery_test_report" time="0.130s" /></testsuite>
<testsuite errors="0" failures="0" hostname="devkvm01-jenkins" name="unittest" skipped="0" tests="24" time="4.545s"><testcase classname="src/test/python/t0/backend/test_syslog.testsyslog" file="test_syslog.py" name="test_syslog" time="4.545s" /></testsuite>
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: You are overwriting `testcase` attributes inside the loop on each line. There should be one `ET.Element('testcase')` for each line appended to `testsuite` and print it outside the loop.

Comment: Hey..made the changes you suggested and the script works..Thanks!